# List Comprehensions to replace element

Tags: list-comprehension

for i in range(1, len(A)):
        A[i] = A[i-1] + A[i]

Comment: What is your input/expected output?

Comment: Input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Ouput = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28] But with A = [A[i-1]+A[i] for i in range(1, len(A))] the outṕut only is [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

Comment: Hint: Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)

Comment: How about `A[0]`? Your formula can only apply to index larger than 0 but there will be an index 0. If you don't care about the value of `A[0]`, you can use `range(len(A))`. Then `A[0] = A[-1] + A[0]`. If you want a specific value of `A[0]`. I don't know how to achieve it in a single list comprehension.

Comment: @zhangyangyu I think he's made it pretty obvious that `A[0]` retains it's original value.

Comment: When I was commenting, the question has not been edited yet. @RyanHaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with a list comprehension as they don't allow assignments.

You can use a simple generator function:

```
def func(lis):
    yield lis[0]
    for i,x in enumerate(lis[1:],1):
        lis[i] = lis[i-1] + x
        yield lis[i]

>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(func(A))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
```

Answer (score 1):

though less efficient, this does give the desired output.  But I think I'm getting closer to O(n**2) on this one.

```
A = [sum(A[:i+1]) for i, _ in enumerate(A)]
```

afaik this can't be done with a list comprehension the way you want to.  I would suggest using the for loop version you've provided.  Even if it was possible with a list comprehension, there's no point when you can just modify the list in place.

Comment: It is `A[i] = A[i] + A[i-1]`. Your list comprehension is wrong.

Comment: @zhangyangyu it's the same output, it just performs it differently.

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood the question. He wants a in place replacement. I have changed the comments of you answer. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
def func(L):
    it =  iter(L)
    v = it.next()
    yield v
    for x in it:
        v += x
        yield v

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]     
print list(func(A))
```

This creates an iterator that returns one value at the time. To get the full new list at once you need to use a list() call around the function call, like:

```
list(func(A))
```

This generator function should work on any iterable (also those that don't support getting value based on index, like L[0])

I don't think there's an efficient way to do this with a comprehension list.

Answer (score 0):

Use B (another temporary variable).

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution use `reduce`:

```
>>> the_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> reduce(lambda result, x: result+[result[-1] + x] ,the_list, [0])[1:]
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```